# Display flex in itext7.pdfhtml

Tags: itext7, pdfhtml

I'm using the itext7.pdfhtml 4.0.5 library, and I'm getting an error when generating a PDF from the following HTML code.

teste

teste2

The error received:

---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at iText.Layout.Margincollapse.MarginsCollapse.JoinMargin(MarginsCollapse marginsCollapse)
at iText.Layout.Margincollapse.MarginsCollapseHandler.UpdateCollapseBeforeIfPrevKidIsFirstAndSelfCollapsed(Margin
collapseAfter)
at iText.Layout.Margincollapse.MarginsCollapseHandler.EndChildMarginsHandling(Rectangle layoutBox)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.BlockRenderer.Layout(LayoutContext layoutContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.ListRenderer.Layout(LayoutContext layoutContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.BlockRenderer.Layout(LayoutContext layoutContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.BlockRenderer.Layout(LayoutContext layoutContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.BlockRenderer.Layout(LayoutContext layoutContext)
at iText.Layout.Renderer.RootRenderer.AddChild(IRenderer renderer)
at iText.Layout.RootElement`1.CreateAndAddRendererSubTree(IElement element) at iText.Layout.RootElement`1.Add(IBlockElement element)
at iText.Layout.Document.Add(IBlockElement element)
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Document , Object )
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid2[T0,T1](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)

In testing, the UL list with display:flex always generates the above error. Are there any adjustments without having to change the HTML and CSS?

Thanks

By removing display:flex, PDF generation works without errors.

Comment: I just ran into a similar thing where the div was display:flex with a table inside of it (since flex-direction: column wasn't working for me in this version).
NullReferenceException was in iText.Layout.Renderer.TableRenderer.RetrieveWidth. That took a long time to find the culprit.